# Gulp: abort build, if command line argument missing

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I've written a gulp build which pipes several tasks, all depending on a mandatory argument, which is read from command line, using `yargs` plugin.

Lets say I have

```
gulp.task('myBuild', function () {
  return gulp.src('./' + <providedSubDir> + '/')

    .pipe(// do something or fail if <providedSubDir> is missing)

    .pipe(gulp.dest('./' + providedSubDir + '/'));
});
```

How can I now fail if the mandatory parameter `providedSubDir` is not provided upon call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just throw an error if it is not set:

```
gulp.task('myBuild', function () {
    if (providedSubdir === undefined)
        throw new Error("you need to specify `providedSubdir`");

    // Rest of the task
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this rapid answer!